# How to break after the label in a custom list environment

Tags: lists, line-breaking, environments

I'm trying to create a list environment that labels each item in a certain way. Honestly I could just manually do it but I wanted to learn more about the environment creation processes so I tried to do it by hand. Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcounter{Week}
\newenvironment{Weeks}
   {\begin{list}{{\Large \bf Week \arabic{Week}:}}%
       {%
         \setlength\labelwidth{.25in}%
         \setlength\leftmargin{0in}%
         \setlength\itemsep{24 pt}%
         \usecounter{Week}}%
       }%
   {%
   \end{list}%
   }%
\begin{document}
\begin{Weeks}
\item This is a test
\item 2nd test
\end{Weeks}
\end{document}
```

It mostly does what I want, but I wanted to ask if there was a way for me to in addition to listing each line with the label, is it possible to include a line break so that the text you add appears on the next line after the label "Week *x*:"? I know I could manually just add the line break on each item -- I just want to learn how to do this in another way in the enviorontment definition code.

Answer (score 3):

First, as @ChristianHupfer alredy noted in the comments of the OP, don't use `\bf`. Alternatively LaTeX defines the analogous `\bfseries`. Secondly, the `fullpage` package is also deprecated. `geometry` is the canonical way to set up the page geometry.

Regarding the solution I recommend to first abstract the formatting of the list labels into an auxiliary macro -- it comes in handy later on:

```
\newcommand*\marklabel[1]{\bgroup\Large\bfseries#1\egroup}
```

Then you can define an alternative `\item`-like macro:

```
\newcommand*\weekitem[1][]{%
  \expandafter\ltxitem
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
  \leavevmode\par\vskip1em\par\noindent
}
```

(where `\ltxitem` will be a copy of the default `\item` macro.)

Note that `\weekitem` mantains the ability to specify an alternative label by hand via the optional argument. Finally in the list header in the `\newenvironment` definition you specify that `\item` should be let to `\weekitem`:

```
\newenvironment{Weeks}{%
  \begin{list}{{\marklabel{Week \arabic{Week}}:}}{%
    \setlength\labelwidth{.25in}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{0in}%
    \setlength\itemsep{24pt}%
    \usecounter{Week}%
    \let\ltxitem\item
    \let\item\weekitem}%
}{%
  \end{list}%
}
```

[image: showcase]

#### Complete Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\marklabel[1]{\bgroup\Large\bfseries#1\egroup}
\newcounter{Week}
\newenvironment{Weeks}{%
  \begin{list}{{\marklabel{Week \arabic{Week}}:}}{%
    \setlength\labelwidth{.25in}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{0in}%
    \setlength\itemsep{24pt}%
    \usecounter{Week}%
    \let\ltxitem\item
    \let\item\weekitem}%
}{%
  \end{list}%
}
\newcommand*\weekitem[1][]{%
  \expandafter\ltxitem
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
  \leavevmode\par\vskip1em\par\noindent
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Weeks}
  \item This is a test. \lipsum[1]
  \item 2nd test
  \item[\marklabel{Addendum}:] final test
\end{Weeks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, may, I did not notice `fullpage` at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can change definition of `item` to add line break after item label

```
\let\olditem\item
\def\item{\olditem\leavevmode\newline}
```

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[empty,in]{fullpage}
\newcounter{Week}
\newenvironment{Weeks}
   {\begin{list}{{\Large \bfseries Week \arabic{Week}:}}%
       {%
         \let\olditem\item
         \def\item{\olditem\leavevmode\newline}
         \setlength\labelwidth{.25in}%
         \setlength\leftmargin{0in}%
         \setlength\itemsep{24 pt}%
         \usecounter{Week}}%
       }%
   {%
   \end{list}%
   }%
\begin{document}


\begin{Weeks}
\item This is a test
\item 2nd test
\end{Weeks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose another variant for the `Weeks` environment, based on `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[empty,in]{fullpage}

\usepackage{enumitem, calc} %
 \newlist{Weeks}{enumerate}{1}
 \setlist[Weeks]{label=\raisebox{0pt}[3.5ex][1.5ex]{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{Week \arabic*}}, font =\Large\bfseries, wide = 0pt, itemsep=24pt, leftmargin=\widthof{\Large\textbf{Week}} }
\usepackage{showframe} %
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}


\begin{document}

Text text text text

\begin{Weeks}
  \item This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

  \item 2nd test
\end{Weeks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `enumitem` and defining `Weeks` with a `\newlist`.

The counter is called `Weeksi` (autodefined by `enumerate`)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[empty,in]{fullpage}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlist{Weeks}{enumerate}{1}

\AtBeginEnvironment{Weeks}{%\
  \xapptocmd{\item}{%
    \leavevmode\par%
    }{\typeout{Success}}{}
}
\setlist[Weeks,1]{label={\Large \bfseries Week {\arabic*}:},itemsep=24pt, labelwidth=.25in,labelindent=!,listparindent=0em}


\begin{document}

\begin{Weeks}
\item This is a test
\item 2nd test
\item Another Test
\item The \arabic{Weeksi}th Week!
\end{Weeks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\item[...]` won't work any longer, of course